# Formatting dates to specific format

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

im wondering if i can transform this kind of string "2012-11-09 11:30:00" to this "tuesday 9th of November at 11h30"
I can't figure out witch methods of NSDateFormatter i should use.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, my answer is informing you that the 9th of November 2012 is not a tuesday, but a friday ;)

Comment: LOL, great reflex, i am just giving an example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *myDateString = @"2012-11-09 11:30:00";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString: myDateString];

formatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE d 'of' MMMM 'at' HH'h'mm";
NSString *myNewDateString = [formatter stringFromDate: myDate];
```

(I did not include `release`, as I'm used to working with ARC).

Here is the output I get :

> Friday 9 of November at 11h30

[Here](http://waracle.net/mobile/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/) is a list of the formatters you can use.

Please note that this does not include the "st", "nd", "rd" and "th" after the day. Have a look over SO, there are plenty of questions about this.

You can also set `formatter.locale` to `@"FR_fr"` or anything else to change the language for the day/month.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's an out of the box method for getting exactly what you want, but this should get you going:
http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/date-and-time/date-and-time-examples